# call back methods with closure?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

This is a very specific question i got from treehouse
part one: We're writing an app to fetch the most recent blog posts from the Treehouse blog. This requires making a network request using asynchronous methods that execute in the background. For that we need a closure.
Create a method called fetchTreehouseBlogPosts, that has a single parameter - a completion handler. The closure has three parameters: a data object containing the results of the request as type NSData!, the HTTP response object from our request as type NSURLResponse!, an error object as type NSError!, and a return type of void.

```
/////////////I get this part and the code is correct as following: 

typealias BlogPostCompletion = ((NSData!, NSURLResponse!, NSError!) -> Void)

func fetchTreehouseBlogPosts(completion: BlogPostCompletion){}

///////////This is the part i cant get right. Please help

Copy paste the following code inside the body of the method:

let blogURL = NSURL(string: "http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/")
  let requestURL = NSURL(string: "get_recent_summary/?count=20", relativeToURL: blogURL)

  let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)

  let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
  let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

  // Add your code between the comments

  // Add code above

  dataTask.resume()
```

Your job is to create a data task (not a download task), named dataTask, with a completion handler that returns the results of the data task. Add this data task between the commented section.
Once that's done, within the body of the data task, return the results to the fetchTreehouseBlogPosts method's completion handler.

Comment: So if I get this right, you want to properly use your completion, which you've set up in your parameter, as a return? So you just want the syntax for that?

Comment: Thanks Kevin! I got something like the following im not sure if this will make sense to you..   I think they want something like this format:

        let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (let data, let response, let error) in
            
            // 1. Check HTTP response for successful GET request
            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
             

                    let jsonDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as? [String: AnyObject]
                    completion(jsonDictionary)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you name the type too. After dataTask include the NSURLSessionDataTask like so...

let dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {}....

& then proceed with your statements.

Answer (score 0):

```c
import Foundation

// Add your code below
typealias BlogPostCompletion = ((NSData!, NSURLResponse!, NSError!) -> Void)

func fetchTreehouseBlogPosts(completion: BlogPostCompletion) {

  let blogURL = NSURL(string: "http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/")
  let requestURL = NSURL(string: "get_recent_summary/?count=20", relativeToURL: blogURL)

  let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)

  let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
  let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

   let dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask  = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
   (let data, let response, let error) in
     completion(data, response, error)
   }

   dataTask.resume()
}
```